# V-If and V-else questions (Vue and Firebase Real-time Database)

Tags: vue.js, firebase-realtime-database

I'm working on a web application using Vue and Firebase-Real-time Database. I managed to include all the CRUD functions following several tutorials in Youtube. The problem right now is that i am unable to show or hide a certain element when changing the {Edit:} condition of the user via v-if/v-else. Below will be the code;

```
<template>
    <div class="row">
    <div class="container">
        <table class="table table-striped">

            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Email</th>
                    <th>ID</th>
                    <th>Actions</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>

                <tbody v-for="userProfile in Users" :key="userProfile.key">
                <tr v-if="userProfile.edit"> 
                    <td>{{userProfile.username}}</td>
                    <td>{{userProfile.email}}</td>
                    <td>{{userProfile.userId}}</td>

                    
                    <td>

                    <button @click.prevent="updateUser(userProfile.key)" class="btn btn-primary"> Update </button>
                            
                    <button @click.prevent="removeUser(userProfile.key)" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>

                    </td>
                </tr>

                <tr v-else>
                    
                        <td> <input type="text" v-model="userProfile.username"> </td>
                        <td> <input type="text" v-model="userProfile.email"> </td>
                        <td> <input type="text" v-model="userProfile.userId"> </td>

                        <td>
                        
                        <button @click.prevent="saveUser(userProfile)" class="btn btn-primary"> Save </button>
                        <button @click.prevent="cancel(userProfile.key)" class="btn btn-danger"> Cancel </button>

                        </td>
            
                </tr>
                </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

As for my script

```
import { usersRef } from '../main.js';

export default {
    data() {
        return {
            Users: [],
        }
    },

    created() {
        usersRef.once('value', (Users) => {
            Users.forEach((doc) => {
                this.Users.push({
                    key: doc.key,
                    email: doc.child('email').val(),
                    username: doc.child('username').val(),
                    userId: doc.child('userId').val(),

                
                })
             })
        })
    },

    methods:{
        removeUser: function(key) {
                usersRef.child(key).remove()
                .then(function() {
                    console.log("deleted Sucessfully");
                    alert("Sucessfully Deleted");
                }).catch(function(error) {
                    console.log(error);
                });
        },
        updateUser: function(key) {

                usersRef.child(key).update({edit:false})
                .then(function() {
                    console.log("update Sucessfully");
                    alert("Sucessfully Update");
                }).catch(function(error) {
                    console.log(error);
                });
        },
        cancel:function(key){
            usersRef.child(key).update({edit:false})
        },

        saveUser:function(userProfile) {
            const key = userProfile.key;
            usersRef.child(key).set({username:userProfile.username,email:userProfile.email,userId:userProfile.userId,edit:true})
            .then(function() {
                    console.log("Saved Sucessfully");
                    alert("Successfully Saved");
                }).catch(function(error) {
                    console.log(error);
                });
        }          
    }
 }
```

am i doing something wrong? thanks in advance!

Comment: how are you updating userProfile.edit? It might be because the UsersRef object you created is not "reactive" in Vue terminology, in other words, Vue does not know user.edit has changed and won't update the virtual DOM, see https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out! now it's working again as intended! just as you said, i need to reactive it by calling the .edit when i push the data. Really Appreciate the fast response!